# GUI фреймворки wxPython и GTK в коммерческой разработке

Tags: gtk, wxpython, wxwidgets, pygtk

Возник такой вопрос: используются ли в коммерческой разработке GUI фреймворки: wxPython (wrapper над wxWidgets) и GTK(PyGTK, gtkmm)?

Желательно, чтобы ответили те, которые за последние 1-2 года использовали их (если, конечно, использовали). Вообще, есть ли смысл в их возможно глубоком изучении или всё-таки доминанты: WinForms, Swing, WPF, Qt и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, есть же коммерческое ПО под линь: Nero, Zend и др. Так они, похоже, на GTK сделаны. Под винду, кажется, на GTK+ вообще очень мало пишут

Answer (score 1):

стоит. лицензия не помеха. тем более после изучения gtk понять swing проще

Comment: понять-то проще - это да, а сам-то по себе GTK+ используется где-нить?